# Use includeexpr to make multiple changes

Tags: vimrc, set

I know that `gf` will use `includeexpr` to modify the name and make another attempt to find said file. However I need to make two modifications to the term being used to seed the search (i.e., the text under the cursor when `gf` is pressed.

The Chef DSL on top of Ruby lets you include recipes from the same cookbook using this statement:

`include_recipe ::foo`

The underlying file is called `foo.rb`. So I need to strip off the leading colons, and tack on a `.rb`. One is easy, but I'm not sure how to do both.

`:set includeexpr=substitute(v.fname,'::','','')`

will remove the leading colons. How do I add the `.rb`?

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate `v:fname` with `'.rb'` inside `substitute`:

```
:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'::\\(.*\\)','\\1.rb','')
```

EDIT:

I've changed it a bit, it appears that whitespaces after coma is not allowed.

Comment: I tried this but I get an "E518 Unknown option . " error. I tried "+" as a concatenation operator but that also failed.

Comment: Your setup doesn't include the '::' in the file name, but mine appears to be doing that. Here's my isfname setting, I'm curious if yours is different: `isfname=@,48-57,/,.,-,_,+,,,#,$,%,~,=,:`

Comment: Ah, I thought there is something like, mine was similar, but without `:`, cool - that's something I learned today :) I adjusted my answer to that